# What does "_" .(insert function) do in JavaScript? (React example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still rather new to building React/Redux apps. I have been building applications and looking at the code of other applications to learn best practice.

Looking over someone's Reducer, many of the case statements looked like so:

```
case RECEIVE_CURRENT_TEAM:
  return _.merge({}, state, {current_team: action.team})
```

I wanted to know what _. before merge is doing.

The way I would write the above in my reducer is as follows:

```
case RECEIVE_CURRENT_TEAM:
  return merge({}, state, {current_team: action.team})
```

I wanted to know the benefit if there was any to _. as I am at the very beginning of building out my next app.

I found some info, but it was vague and linked documentation for _ extend in JavaScript, but the link was broken.

http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#extend

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` is not a Javascript feature. It is a commonly-used library.

It could either be a reference to [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) or [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/).

Both libraries have great documentation so you can lookup what each function does.

Answer (score 4):

The other folks have mentioned that `_` is usually either lodash or underscore, but you should know there's nothing mystical or magical about these functions/libraries.  You can make one too.

```js
var _ = (function() {
 
  function greet() {
   console.log("hi there!");
  }
  
  return {
   greet
  }
  
})()

_.greet();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want lodash/underscore (which exactly is `_`), you may try for example ES7 syntax

```
Object.assign({}, state, {current_team: action.team})
```

or

```
{ ...state, current_team: action.team }
```